# Motherboard Temperature High After Install Linux

Tags: laptop, asus, bios, motherboard

I switched from windows to linux but i have a problem, when I normal use Motherboard chip get high temperature up 60c° and cpu tmp is 53c°, gpu 48c°, but in past I use windows not have this problem.

System:

```
Asus Tuf 15 - i5, rtx 3050
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
```